Missing event when trying to fetch new tokens data
I am listening to new raydium pools using the connection.onLogs() rpc method with the filter of raydium program id, so I get logs of only raydium program, but some of the tx logs doesn't come while listening due to which we don't get some pools.
One solution which I tried is making a scheduler which fetches transactions of raydium program every second and then filter the transactions which we need, but as rpc methods (getSignaturesForAddress) provide max 1000 signatures and there are more than 1000 txns/sec in raydium program so we may miss txns which are not present in those 1000 which the rpc method returns.
I also tried using the "before" and "until" filters for getSignaturesForAddress method but it takes a long time when there are more than 3k txns/sec.
Any idea?

You're doing the right thing unfortunately. Maybe you can setup multiple listeners for onLogs to make sure nothing is missed, but otherwise this is all correct.
